# Quantile based privilege limits?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stackexchange-2.0, privileges

Something in voice of [Lower reputation limit for editing on SE betas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68096/lower-reputation-limit-for-editing-on-se-betas).

The recent creation of many SE2.0 sites showed that each of them has its own voting dynamics and user structure, yet all of them are using same privilege limits; IMO this only makes smaller and younger sites suffer from the lack of active editors and retaggers.

So, I would propose the following system; at first, the limits would be expressed in reputation quantiles (i.e. you must have more reputation than x per cent of 200+ users) or in private beta levels, whatever is higher, and so grow with the site to finally stop when they reach SO levels. To simplify implementation, there can be also only-growing constraint and, for instance, only weekly recalc. Possibly this system should also cover only some priviledges; yet I think other post edit, retag and close voting are essential.

EDIT: I tried to improve the idea to handle the critic; it could look like this:

> Note that because this site is in
> start-up, some limits are temporarly
> lowered to reflect current reputation
> structure ([link]you can find boring
> mathematical details here[/link]):
>
> ```
> 15     Vote up
> 15     Flag offensive
> 50     Leave comments†
> 100    Edit community wiki posts 
> 125    Vote down (costs 1 rep)
> 200    Reduced advertising
> 250    Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions 
> 500    Retag questions (temporarly lowered to 317)
> 1000   Show total up and down vote counts 
> 1500   Create new tags (temporarly lowered to 425)
> 2000   Edit other people's posts (temporarly lowered to 710)
> 3000   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions (temporarly lowered to 1231)
> 10000  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> ```

Then the user will know that she/he shouldn't expect that her/his privilege is permanent if she/he just have reached the temporary limit, it all looks pretty simple (so called "I am smarter than you proof"), finally critical levels are preserved.

Comment: I'm imagining feedback along the lines of "3 times now, I've got near the rep I need, just as it changes! [rage-quit]"

Comment: What about "I'm in top-7, there is a stream of bad questions and I can do nothing! [frustration-lost interest]"?

Answer (score 4):

**This has complexity that exceeds its benefits.**

For sites that only have experienced power users of the SE system, it would be a good, graduated approach.

But for sites that are trying to attract new users who already have to learn a whole new approach to Q&A, an algebraic bridge to connect two tiered, tabular systems is a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

This could be implemented as the questioner mentions in his edit (as per the example).

If that is still to complex for some people, then it could be made more simply without throwing out the idea altogether:

Instead of infinitely many possibilities for rep limits, as the questioner proposed, there could be as few as 2, and even that would help the situation.

e.g. 1:

> Note that because this site is in start-up, all limits temporarily
>   **HALF** those listed here:
>
> ```
> 15     Vote up
> 15     Flag offensive
> 50     Leave comments†
> 100    Edit community wiki posts 
> 125    Vote down (costs 1 rep)
> 200    Reduced advertising
> 250    Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions 
> 500    Retag questions
> 1000   Show total up and down vote counts 
> 1500   Create new tags
> 2000   Edit other people's posts
> 3000   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
> 10000  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> ```

...and if that is not clear enough, you can list the new limits while still keeping them at fixed values during start-up mode (and of course you could make it so that they are not all exactly half, if you don't mind an extra bit of complexity).

e.g. 2:

> Note that because this site is in start-up, all limits temporarily **HALF** the usual value:
>
> ```
> 15     (now 7)     Vote up
> 15     (now 7)     Flag offensive
> 50     (now 25)    Leave comments†
> 100    (now 50)    Edit community wiki posts 
> 125    (now 62)    Vote down (costs 1 rep)
> 200    (now 100)   Reduced advertising
> 250    (now 125)   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions 
> 500    (now 250)   Retag questions
> 1000   (now 500)   Show total up and down vote counts 
> 1500   (now 750)   Create new tags
> 2000   (now 1000)  Edit other people's posts
> 3000   (now 1500)  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
> 10000  (now 5000)  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> ```

Comment: I would suggest that suddenly taking away privileges when going from small to large "mode" might alienate people so I’d suggest if someone has gained a privilege during small mode they can only loose it again by going below the small mode rep limit (even if the site has changed to large mode)